# Is it possible to make zIndex of a subview in sectionlist's row higher than other row?

Tags: listview, react-native, z-index, react-native-flatlist

Hi I am trying to make a tooltip-like chatBubble UI that can be used also in scrollable views (like flatlist, sectionlist, listview...)

here's my renderItem codes for SectionList.

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.row}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <Text>ToolTipComponent has to be below this text...</Text>
                <ToopTipComponent style={styles.rowText}/>
            <TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
     );
}
```

I am going to make ToolTipComponent get visible by Animated.timing when click the button, and pop away some milliseconds later. ToolTipComponent's height is quite bigger than each row's height, so it has to exceed the bound of the row and overlay the next row.
But I found that the bottom of each row's ToolTipComponent is overlaid by the next row. I think that rows are rendered in a series so the row rendered next might overlays the previous row's subviews.

Is it possible to make a row's sub view which could get out of the bound not overlaid by the next row?